# git 2.32 git push -u origin master Nothing happens

Tags: git, github

I've starting to use git/github and I'm stucked on how to push my codes to github. I'm following some tutorials and when I type `git push -u origin master`  nothing is happening, no logins screens opens as I've seen in this tutorials. I reallized that the  process "credential manager" is running even after I had closed my git prompt. I did the same process in two different laptops, same issue. I'd like to know if is a problem of the version 2.32
thanks.
[image]

When I say nothing, means getting stuck in this line git push -u origin master. When I try to close git bash,the screen in print bellow show to me.

Comment: Put some screenshots or some error log so people can find what's wrong.

Comment: Without providing the exact error log it is very hard to suggest any solution.

Comment: The “processes are running” means it isn’t done.

Comment: This problem seems to be new in the latest Git-for-Windows. If your "start the credential manager first" trick works for everyone, this will be the definitive answer until the bug gets fixed. :-)

Answer (score 3):

When you say "nothing is happening", do you mean I waited for less than 2 minutes and it appeared as though nothing happened? In that case it might be the credential manager. See issue [git-credential-manager-core hangs on get #364](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core/issues/364). To see more logging it might be useful to run the command `$ GIT_TRACE=1 GIT_TRANSFER_TRACE=1 GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 GIT_TRACE_PERFORMANCE=1 GCM_TRACE=1 git push -u origin master`. Your problem might be fixed by setting the credential provider. For a github server you can do this `$ GCM_PROVIDER=github git push -u origin master`. If that worked you can set this permanently with `$ git config --global credential.github.com.provider github`. You should probably also look in the [Configuration options configuration](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core/blob/main/docs/configuration.md).

If all the above sounds too complicated you can downgrade git for windows to 2.30. The installer can be found here:
https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.30.2.windows.1/Git-2.30.2-64-bit.exe

Comment: where shoul I paste this command , in a git bash?, didn't work. Thanks for previous version, but it didn't work as well.
thanks for help me.

Comment: Copy paste it in git bash. Don’t include the dollar sign. It shoul log more.

Answer (score 1):

well, I had to go to C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core and start the app git-credential-manager.exe and put my credentials. Doesnt make sense, coz , after the command "push" an github screen should appear to me. I really didnt understand why it has worked.

Comment: This might be a new bug.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue, so I downloaded GitHub Desktop version and things worked for me. It is user friendly.

Answer (score 0):

While installing GIT on Windows I chose Git Credential Manager instead of new Git Credential Manager Core and it solved this problem