# Git Clone - Can't clone repository

Tags: git, repository, clone

I'm trying to `git clone https://github.com/dp32350/UshtrimeWeb.git`
, but it stays just so without any error message:

[image]

Comment: `https://github.com/dp32350/UWeb.git` results in a 404 not found - maybe that is why?

Comment: That repository is either private or it doesn't exist.

Comment: Could it be the same as this push problem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67960886/7976758 ? See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67931716/git-push-doesnt-do-anything-over-https#comment120072116_67931716

Answer (score 0):

You can get more detail with:

`env GIT_TRACE=1 GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git clone --verbose git clone https://github.com/dp32350/UshtrimeWeb.git`

Probably one of:

- local file permissions
- wrong url
- wrongly setup github credentials